# Абсолютное позиционирование картинок в ячейке таблицы

Tags: css, bootstrap

В ячейке таблицы есть 2 картинки. Как сделать, что бы картинка `smal.png` была в левом верхнем углу ячейки поверх картинки `big.png`, а картинка `big.png` - по центру ячейки?

```
<td>
    <img src="smal.png">
    <img src="big.png">
</td>
```

Comment: через позиционирование

Answer (score 0):

```css
.table-td {
  position: relative
}

.table-image_small {
  z-index: 100;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-td">
      <img class="table-image table-image_big" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x200?text=big">
      <img class="table-image table-image_small" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40/FFAAAA/?text=small">
    </td>
    <td class="table-td">
      <img class="table-image table-image_big" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x200?text=big">
      <img class="table-image table-image_small" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40/FFAAAA/?text=small">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="table-row">
    <td class="table-td">
      <img class="table-image table-image_big" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x200?text=big">
      <img class="table-image table-image_small" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40/FFAAAA/?text=small">
    </td>
    <td class="table-td">
      <img class="table-image table-image_big" src="http://via.placeholder.com/250x200?text=big">
      <img class="table-image table-image_small" src="http://via.placeholder.com/40x40/FFAAAA/?text=small">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Только вместо тегов `<div>` у вас будут `<img>`.

```css
td.relative {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid #bdc3c7;
}

    td.relative div.absolute {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        background-color: #99abd5;
        z-index: 2;
    }
    
    td.relative div.center {
        width: 150px;
        height: 150px;
        background-color: #b8c9f1;
        z-index: 1;
    }
```

```html
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="relative">
            <div class="absolute"></div>
            <div class="center"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```